# Service Fabric SDK 2.2.207 how to change data and log paths?

Tags: configuration, sdk, azure-service-fabric

Since installing Service Fabric SDK 2.2.207 I'm not able to change the cluster data and log paths (with previous SDKs I could).

I tried:

1. Editing the registry keys in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Service Fabric - they just revert back to C:\SfDevCluster\data and C:\SfDevCluster\log when the cluster is created.
2. Running poweshell: & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1" -PathToClusterDataRoot d:\SfDevCluster\data -PathToClusterLogRoot d:\SfDevCluster\log - this works successfully but upon changing the cluster mode to 1-node (newly available configuration with this SDK), the cluster moves to the C drive.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you switch cluster mode on local dev box, existing cluster is removed and a new one is created. You can pass use \DevClusterSetup.ps1 to switch mode from 5->1 node, by passing -CreateOneNodeCluster to create one node cluster and pass Data and Log root paths to it as well.